# Ember data model created with createRecord with no params does not appear

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We have an example ember app where we CRUD recipes. For the route where we create a new Recipe, if we pass attributes into createRecord like so:

```
Cookbook.RecipesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    Cookbook.Recipe.createRecord(title: "blank")
```

the recipe appears immediately in the list on the left side of the screen. Here's the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/itehib/1/edit) to show what I mean

However, if I create the recipe without args a la

```
Cookbook.Recipe.createRecord()
```

I don't see the recipe appear in the list until I edit one of the attributes. This happens even though I've specified default values, as proved by this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/apeseq/2/edit).

My question is: Why does this happen and how can I create a record with no params specified and still have it show up immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your jsbin's the only thing you are missing is `@get('store').commit()` after you create the empty record.

Here an example:

```
Cookbook.RecipesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
   Cookbook.Recipe.createRecord()
   @get('store').commit()
```

and here your working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oxoboq/2/edit). I've added id's in parenthesis to the template so you can see the record is created correctly.

**EDIT** After your comment I've made some changes to the **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oxoboq/5/edit)**, basically what I've changed is this:

```
Cookbook.RecipesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    controller.startEditing()

Cookbook.RecipesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  startEditing: ->
    @controllerFor('recipes').pushObject(Cookbook.Recipe.createRecord())
```

I've added the method `startEditing` for convenience (you can call it what ever you want).
In the `startEditing` method as you can see we get the `recipesController` and add a new record to the `content` array, this causes the new recipe to show up even if not commited to the store. Give it a try.

Hope it helps

Comment: I actually have a case where I want it to show up before the commit happens. I want the record to show up in the list view before I send it back to the server with commit.

Comment: @ChrisNelson I've edited my answer, give it another try and let me know if it works now.

Comment: So hat causes it to show up immediately, which is awesome. But as soon as I edit I see duplicate entries in the list view :(

Answer (score 0):

So it seems pretty hacky, but here's how I got this working the way I wanted it to:

```
 Cookbook.RecipesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
   model: ->
     recipe = Cookbook.Recipe.createRecord()
     @controllerFor('recipes').get("content").addReference(recipe.get("_reference"))
     recipe
```

I don't know if this is kosher, at all, but it seems to work. Feedback and improvements are welcome. I won't mark this as answered for a few days to give anyone else a chance to come up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

look into the HTML and you will see that the `<li>` element has been created, but the `title` property of this model is empty, so the new recipe doesn't show up in the list.

```js
<li>
    <a id="ember413" class="ember-view" href="#/recipes/ember369">
         <script id="metamorph-12-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
         <script id="metamorph-12-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    </a>
</li>
```